# How to collect Rust code coverage when running remote tests?

Tags: rust, code-coverage, gcov, llvm-cov, kcov

I found couple of tools that generate code coverage report (like `grcov`, `tarpaulin`, `llvm-cov` & `kcov`) for Rust code when running unit tests or when triggered by `cargo`.

But in our case we have remote python tests that are interacting with the remote server written in Rust. How can I instrument and collect such coverage report?

Answer (score 1):

Have a similar solution which we tackled using LLVM source based code coverage: [Source Based Code Coverage](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/SourceBasedCodeCoverage.html). You will require LLVM installation.

Here are the steps:

1. Build the rust server with additional Rustflags.

```
                 "-C", "instrument-coverage",
                 "-C", "llvm-args=-runtime-counter-relocation",
```

2. Add the env variable to locate the collected coverage file.

   `export LLVM_PROFILE_FILE="/tmp/server_%p%c.profraw"`
3. After the tests, end the server process and collect the the generated profraw files in a `cov_dir` and the server binary in  `bin_dir`. Use grcov (cargo install grcov) to generate an html report:

```
grcov ./cov_dir -b ./bin_dir --llvm-path ${LLVM_BIN_DIR} -s ${SRC} -t html
```